# Empty file in thymeleaf after valdiation

Tags: java, validation, thymeleaf, filefield

I have a thymeleaf form with file field and checkbox. Both are required

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/upload}"
      th:object="${data}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" th:field="*{exampleFile}" accept="application/pdf"/>
<div class="error" (...) />

<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{isOwner}"/>
<div class="error" (...) />

(...)

</form>
```

and post method

```
@PostMapping("upload")
public String upload(@Valid @ModelAttribute("data") DataDTO data, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "upload";
    }

(...)

    return "redirect:/confirm";
}
```

When I select a file but don't check a checkbox and submit a form then I have validation error on checkbox.

there is no validation error on file file (it'a correct) but this field is empty and I need to select file again.

I need the form not to delete the file during validation

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a traditional form. This would require a file input read a file based on the field's value, which would be a security violation. You could post the form data using JavaScript (AJAX) and never leave the page and update the validation information based on the AJAX result.